# Rust 1k TCP connection limit

Tags: linux, tcp, rust

I'm writing a high-throughput multi-threaded Rust server.  The server needs to handle in the neighborhood of 10-20k connections at time.

I've got the program written and its super fast, however, it only allows a maximum of 1k connections.  After 1k, the `TCPListener` doesn't return anything else until the current connections are removed.

I don't see anywhere inside Rust to set a connection limit.  Is this a Rust limitation with `core::net` or is this a system limitation?

I'm running on Linux 4.14.15, the development server will be on 4.14.xxxx.  Rust 1.23.0

Comment: What are your ulimits? Is "1k" **exactly** 1000 or is it a different number? What do you mean by "doesn't return anything else" — is it returning an *error*? Is it *blocking*?

Comment: "After 1k, the TCPListener doesn't return anything else until the current connections are removed.", it's impossible you must get a error message, probably, ENFILE error.

Comment: Likely to be a duplicate of [Why do I get connection refused after 1024 connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/923990/155423)

Comment: Thanks guys, checking out the ulimit and learning how to change that did fix the problem.

Comment: To answer your question Shep, the ulimit was 1k = 1024.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it's system limit. If you type `ulimit -n` you will see number of max files open, which I think it is also for sockets.

Try typing `ulimit -n 10000` and then run your application.